# Whom is God conversing with in Genesis 6:7?

Tags: genesis, creation, noah, flood

After lamenting the degradation of humankind God passes judgement on humankind,animals and every creeping things. Its not clear who God was addressing concerning this issue

Genesis 6:7 KJV

> ***And the Lord said***, I will destroy man whom I have created from the face of the earth; both man, and beast, and the creeping thing, and the fowls of the air; for it repenteth me that I have made them.

Immediately after passing judgement on humankind and animals and all creeping things within the immediate context Noah is introduced

Genesis 6:8 KJV

> But Noah found grace in the eyes of the Lord.9 These are the generations of Noah: Noah was a just man and perfect in his generations, and Noah walked with God.10 And Noah begat three sons, Shem, Ham, and Japheth.

Further on still within the same context of this debacle God begins to speak to Noah concerning how he should escape the unfolding calamity

Genesis 6:13-14 KJV

> And God said unto Noah, The end of all flesh is come before me; for the earth is filled with violence through them; and, behold, I will destroy them with the earth.14 Make thee an ark of gopher wood; rooms shalt thou make in the ark, and shalt pitch it within and without with pitch.

Trying to garner understand from the context of this chapter would one be led to believe that God was addressing Noah

TO whom was God talking to in the above text?

Comment: He doesn't *need* to be talking to *anyone*. Moses is simply expressing what God was working through for the record of scripture. (assuming Moses was the one who wrote the first few books). If the foot should say, “Because I am not a hand, I do not belong to the body,” that would not make it any less a part of the body. Who is the 'foot' speaking to? 1Cor 12:15

Comment: Based on context, it is reasonable to view God as addressing Noah. God does not do anything without first telling his prophets (Amos 3:7), and Noah was a prophet of God who would know why God was commanding him to build the ark. The other godly man, Enoch, had died about 70 years before Noah was born. Noah passed on all the information Moses later received and wrote down in Genesis, so Noah would know what God had said, likely because God had told  him directly.

Comment: To a Trinitarian, there is clearly the thought that these are the counsels of Deity. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 1):

The object of God's "conversation" in Gen 6:7 could be any of the following possibilities:

- Himself - God could be talking out loud to Himself
- God was "talking" to no-one but simply thinking these thoughts
- Other heavenly beings (perhaps angels??) such as those described in places like Job 1:6, 2:1, 38:7.

In any case, it does not matter because we are not told.  The fact remains that God thought these things and whether He actually spoke them to anyone else is immaterial.  If it were important, it would have been recorded.